# Been trying to run my discord bot but it keeps saying "ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)"

Tags: python, discord

My code is here below:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

yet for some reason I always get the error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)
```

I don't have nextcord, pycord, or anything else like that installed, so I don't know what is causing the problem. Please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: Try running the command: pip install py-cord

Comment: I've already fixed the problem, but thank you. I had to run it on a virtual environment.

Comment: @SalmonellaBaby Consider answering your own question by describing what worked for you, it could help future readers.